# Swift SpriteKit use of unresolved identifier "SpriteView"

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am following a tutorial to learn about SwiftUI and there is a part which uses SpriteKit. However, when I copy the code on my XCode, I get the error of **unresolved identifier** **SpriteView**.

Here is my code:

First I imported SwiftUI and SpriteKit

```
import SwiftUI
import SpriteKit
```

Then, I created my view:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var scene: SKScene {
        let scene = GameScene()
        scene.size = CGSize(width: 300, height: 500)
        scene.scaleMode = .fill
        return scene
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        SpriteView(scene: scene)
            .frame(width: 300, height: 500)
    }
}
```

And GameScene is a class of SKScene

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        // some code here
    }
    
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        // some code here
    }
}
```

The instructor did not do anything extra, but I do not know my I am getting error.

Answer (score 3):

The tutorial uses Xcode 12. You don’t.